# Boilerplate Visual Studio 2017 RC project fails to deploy to Azure App Service from GitHub

Tags: visual-studio, azure, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2017

I'm attempting to deploy a boilerplate Visual Studio 2017 RC Asp.Net Core web app (no authentication) to an Azure App Service using the GitHub deployment option. The app has not been modified from the boilerplate code; literally: create a new app from the VS template, publish it to GitHub, and deploy to App Service.

**Question**

Are any particular settings necessary for VS 2017 RC apps to deploy to an App Service, or has the App Service SCM (Kudu) tooling simply not yet caught up with the VS 2017 RC project structure?

**Details**

I'm running into two problems that I think are probably related.

***Problem 1***: the MSbuild tools v15.0 don't appear to be installed on the app service. When building, Kudo defaults to v14.0:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"  
Handling .NET Console Application deployment.  
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
```

I added a [custom app setting](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#adding-flags-to-the-msbuild-command-line), `SCM_BUILD_ARGS=-tv:15.0`, to try to force Kudo to use v15.0, but this had no effect. It continued to use v14.0 as before.

***Problem 2***: (and possibly as a result of using MSBuild 14.0): MSBuild issues the following error when attempting to restore NuGet packages:

```
Nothing to do. None of the projects in this solution specify any packages for NuGet to restore.
```

This error message is a little vague, but [until recently](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/685/commits/1c67568d105e23562e4200762a9874996c6ba045) the message would assert that no project containing a `packages.config` or `project.json` file was found in the solution. *Both of these files are deprecated as of VS 2017 RC.* I added an empty project.json file to see if that would fix the issue. The packages appear to be restored but it continues to fail due to missing project.json sections.

**Resolution**

@david-ebbo kindly provided [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40698916/1453907). In his [test repo](https://github.com/davidebbo-test/MvcCoreVS2017RC) you'll find `deploy.cmd` and `.deployment` files. Copy both to the root of your repo. Then update Line 74 of `deploy.cmd` to point to your *.csproj* file. Deploying from GitHub should now succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2236.

The Kudu script generator doesn't yet know how to handle Preview3, but you should be able to use a custom deployment script. The key is to use 'dotnet restore' instead of 'nuget restore' and 'dotnet publish' instead of 'msbuild'. See sample [here](https://github.com/davidebbo-test/CoreNewToolingNoSolution/blob/3075fe763245903d2b59997710446b86e49a018b/deploy.cmd#L70-L79).

We will fix Kudu to handle this soon.

Comment: Thanks David! The sample script looks very helpful.

Comment: Here is another one that was created with VS 2017 RC, and also uses a library: https://github.com/davidebbo-test/MvcCoreVS2017RC

Comment: ^^^ That worked great. Thank you! I'm going to update my question to highlight the resolution.